# JSON: Error Domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm getting an error in my request when i try to consume information from my PHP API:

```
OPTIONS http://api.reddrummer.com/summary.json?api_key=tok 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery.js:130
OPTIONS http://api.reddrummer.com/summary.json?api_key=tok Invalid HTTP status code 405 jquery.js:130
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.reddrummer.com/summary.json?api_key=tok. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

(tok is my token for access the information from the API)

```
(function($){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        tok = window.sessionStorage.getItem("token");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.reddrummer.com/summary.json?api_key=' + tok,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(d) {
              alert("ok");
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert("not ok");
            }
        });
    }, false);
})(jQuery);
```

That's my ajax, so I changed the dataType to receive a jsonp instead of json:

```
(function($){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        tok = window.sessionStorage.getItem("token");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.reddrummer.com/summary.json?api_key=' + tok,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'callback',
            jsonp: false,
            success: function(d) {
              alert("ok");
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert("not ok");
            }
        });
    }, false);
})(jQuery);
```

And now there's another error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : summary.json:2
```

It's an error in my json, so I've verified my json and there's nothing wrong with it:

```
{
    "username": "Guilherme",
    "language": "pt-br",
    "position": "Java Pleno",
    "company_name": "Reddrummer",
    "photo": "http://drumcircle.reddrummer.com/p/photo/user/guiandmag@gmail.com",
    "post": {
        "total_post": "1",
        "total_comments": "1",
        "groups": 1,
        "groups_url": {
            ".Delivery Brasil": "http://drumcircle.reddrummer.com/#houseorgan/2566054"
        },
        "people": 2
    },
    "chart": {
        "_video": 0,
        "_image": 0,
        "project": 0,
        "topic": 0,
        "note": 0,
        "mobile": 0,
        "task": 0,
        "press": 0,
        "bug": 0,
        "reuniao": 1,
        "sap": 0,
        "oracle": 0,
        "sharep": 0,
        "vendas": 0,
        "ideia": 0
    }
}
```

I need some help, because I'm trying to see documentation and many other websites but the error it's always the same when I tried to receive the values from my API with JSONP.

Comment: A JSONP response is not the same as a JSON response. You're getting JSON, so that should be your `dataType`. Seems to me you've got a server problem.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP makes it possible to request service / data from another domain. The format is slightly different than a classic JSON object.

Your service needs to wrap the data into a callback function and passing it as argument. This callback is often dynamic and passed as query string parameter (i.e. jQuery does it automatic by appending 'callback' parameter key).

Imagine URL called by jQuery $.ajax() is `http://api.reddrummer.com/summary.json?api_key=12345&callback=jQuery152031713143712840974_1378285818229&_=1378285824291`, the service needs to return:

```
jQuery152031713143712840974_1378285818229(
{
    "username": "Guilherme",
    "language": "pt-br",
    "position": "Java Pleno",
    "company_name": "Reddrummer",
    "photo": "http://drumcircle.reddrummer.com/p/photo/user/guiandmag@gmail.com",
    "post": {
        "total_post": "1",
        "total_comments": "1",
        "groups": 1,
        "groups_url": {
            ".Delivery Brasil": "http://drumcircle.reddrummer.com/#houseorgan/2566054"
        },
        "people": 2
    },
    "chart": {
        "_video": 0,
        "_image": 0,
        "project": 0,
        "topic": 0,
        "note": 0,
        "mobile": 0,
        "task": 0,
        "press": 0,
        "bug": 0,
        "reuniao": 1,
        "sap": 0,
        "oracle": 0,
        "sharep": 0,
        "vendas": 0,
        "ideia": 0
    }
}
);
```